# tcolorbox not portable between beamer and article

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tcolorbox, article

Consider the following two documents:

(a): An `article` class one which does not compile (key `/tcb/thick` unknown)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows,arrows.meta,shapes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{tcbdummy}[1]{enhanced,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbdummy}{height=4.5cm,overlay={
        \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h1)+(-3cm,-1.5cm) |- ++ (-1.75cm,-.75cm) node[anchor=west,fill=blue!25,text=black] (heading) {Kapitelüberschrift};}
        \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h3)+(-.75cm,-1.8cm) -- ++ (0cm,-1.8cm) node[anchor=west,fill=blue!25,text=black] (subheading) {Abschnittsüberschrift};}
        \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h2)+(-4cm,-2cm) -- ++ (-4.5cm,-4cm) node[anchor=north,fill=blue!25,text=black] (text) {Textkörper};
        \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h4)+(-1.75cm,-2cm) -- (text);
    }}
    {\Large\bfseries Texte zum Testen\tikzmark{ex1-h1}}\vskip.75\baselineskip
        Hier kommt normaler Text.\tikzmark{ex1-h2}\\[.3cm]
        {\large\itshape Lorem ipsum\tikzmark{ex1-h3}}\vskip.5\baselineskip
            Und noch mehr Text\tikzmark{ex1-h4}
\end{tcbdummy}
\end{document}
```

(b): A `beamer` class one which does compile

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows,arrows.meta,shapes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{tcbdummy}[1]{enhanced,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}{Quack}
\begin{tcbdummy}{height=4.5cm,overlay={
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h1)+(-3cm,-1.5cm) |- ++ (-1.75cm,-.75cm) node[anchor=west,fill=blue!25,text=black] (heading) {Kapitelüberschrift};
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h3)+(-.75cm,-1.8cm) -- ++ (0cm,-1.8cm) node[anchor=west,fill=blue!25,text=black] (subheading) {Abschnittsüberschrift};
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h2)+(-4cm,-2cm) -- ++ (-4.5cm,-4cm) node[anchor=north,fill=blue!25,text=black] (text) {Textkörper};
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h4)+(-1.75cm,-2cm) -- (text);
}}
    {\Large\bfseries Texte zum Testen\tikzmark{ex1-h1}}\vskip.75\baselineskip
        Hier kommt normaler Text.\tikzmark{ex1-h2}\\[.3cm]
        {\large\itshape Lorem ipsum\tikzmark{ex1-h3}}\vskip.5\baselineskip
            Und noch mehr Text\tikzmark{ex1-h4}
\end{tcbdummy}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to port the beamer figure to article, but it doesn't work. What's the difference in functionality there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is just two more closing braces. If you remove them everything works fine :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows,arrows.meta,shapes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{tcbdummy}[1]{enhanced,#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbdummy}{height=4.5cm,overlay={
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h1)+(-3cm,-1.5cm) |- ++ (-1.75cm,-.75cm) node[anchor=west,fill=blue!25,text=black] (heading) {Kapitelüberschrift};% no closing brace
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h3)+(-.75cm,-1.8cm) -- ++ (0cm,-1.8cm) node[anchor=west,fill=blue!25,text=black] (subheading) {Abschnittsüberschrift};% no closing brace
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h2)+(-4cm,-2cm) -- ++ (-4.5cm,-4cm) node[anchor=north,fill=blue!25,text=black] (text) {Textkörper};
    \draw[blue,thick,Stealth-,rounded corners] (pic cs:ex1-h4)+(-1.75cm,-2cm) -- (text);
}}
    {\Large\bfseries Texte zum Testen\tikzmark{ex1-h1}}\vskip.75\baselineskip
        Hier kommt normaler Text.\tikzmark{ex1-h2}\\[.3cm]
        {\large\itshape Lorem ipsum\tikzmark{ex1-h3}}\vskip.5\baselineskip
            Und noch mehr Text\tikzmark{ex1-h4}
\end{tcbdummy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't notice that. Thanks.